# Why is the side-by-side configuration incorrect?

Tags: mfc, side-by-side

I installed a video game , but when I try launching it it just says this: 
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

I checked the event log and it says:
Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6195" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I installed many patches but none of them have the exact number (version?)(8.0.50727.6195) and the game still doesn't work. Can you help me please?

PS: I use windows 10 64 bit

Edit: I forgot to mention that I already downloaded the version from this link: microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347 and the one from this link: microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26401 but it still doesn't work. I ran the first one as administrator and then restarted the computer, and then tried the second one. When I ran the second one it says the upgrade patch cannot be installed by the windows installer because the program to be updated may be missing, or the update patch may update a different version of the program.

What am I exactly supposed to do with the program I installed for the first link? I just ran it as administrator but it did nothing.

EDIT 2: The windows just updated the x64 files and the game works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."* - Why don't you read error messages **in full**? With Stack Overflow being for developers, it is kinda expected, that you do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't installed the correct SP1 security patched version.

This is the [one version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347) you need.

Select the 32bit version and install it. See also this [KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2538242/ms11-025-description-of-the-security-update-for-visual-c-2005-sp1-redistributable-package-june-14,-2011).

BTW: Just 1min in Google and you would have found the solution.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. The thing is, I already downloaded the version from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347
and the one from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26401
but it still doesn't work. I ran the first one as administrator and then restarted the computer, and then tried the second one. When I ran the second one it says the upgrade patch cannot be installed by the windows installer because the program to be updated may be missing, or the update patch may update a different version of the program.